# Does noexcept specification of swap has performance impact?

Tags: stl, swap, c++11

The `noexcept` specification on move-constructors are known to have performance implications in C++0x. For example, `std::vector<T>::resize`, `std::vector<T>::reserve` may use a non-throwing move-constructor of T if it can be proven to not throw. The `noexcept` opeator is the way to check that property at compile-time. If noexcept says that T's move-ctor does not throw, T objects will be moved instead of copied most likely achieving higher performance.

My question is about member swap or namespace-level swap for a user-defined class T. C++0x spec spends some effort in exporting noexcept specifications of `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, `std::array:swap` possibly indicating that user-defined classes should try to use the same principle. For instance, `std::pair::swap` is declared as equivalent to:

```
void std::pair::swap(pair& p) noexcept(noexcept(swap(first, p.first)) && noexcept(swap(second, p.second));
```

It basically says that pair's swap will throw if either swapping of `first` or `second` member throws. Swap of `first`, `second` possibly have their own noexcept specifications in terms of their members.

Finally the question: Are there generic algorithms out there (in stl or otherwise) that depending upon the noexcept specification of swap do different things? Moreover, is there a performance implication of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to code that specifically behaves differently when something is noexcept (such as `std::vector`), declaring a function noexcept can allow the compiler to do its own optimizations.  At the very least the compiler doesn't have to keep track of certain things that are involved in exception handling, which might free up registers or execute less instructions among other things.